# Create WCF Client without auto generated proxy

Tags: c#, wcf

looking at

[WCF ChannelFactory vs generating proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698275/wcf-channelfactory-vs-generating-proxy)

appears that the best practice in creating a WCF client is to create a proxy (Not autogenerated).

I've been looking online for a while and i didn't find any complete example(Proxy class, web.config)

Could you provide an example or links to resources?

Answer (score 20):

This article is about exactly what you're asking, I believe:

[WCF the Manual Way... The Right Way](http://code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0809101)

Having shared that, though, creating your proxies manually is probably not always the best possible use of your time.  The article goes into some great reasons for doing so - you'll certainly have more control, your clients may have an easier time, etc. but overall, doing things manually like this will require more of your time, and explaining to users of your service exactly how to use the proxy you provide may be a pain.

There's a reason WCF allows metadata exchange and discovery and VS will auto create proxies for you.

Either way, it's a cool article and a technique well worth learning.

Comment: There's also a video by [Miguel Castro on Extreme WCF](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=122) which explains this visually and in great detail

Comment: Cool Marc!  I'm gonna have to check it out!  :)

Comment: Just finished watching the video...........Great!! That's what i was looking for!! Thanks

Answer (score 11):

This is how I do it.

**Get service contracts and data contracts**

If I have access to the service code, I have all the contracts. If not, I can use **svcutil** or **Add Service Reference** to generate them.

**Make config**

I use **Add Service Reference** just to get the app.config file. I then delete everything else it generates. Edit the app.config as necessary.

**Define factory**

Say I have a service contract `IFooService`:

```
interface IFooServiceChannel : IFooService, IClientChannel { }
```

That is literally it. No members.

**Create factory**

```
fooServiceFactory = new ChannelFactory<IFooServiceChannel>(
                        "NetTcpBinding_IFooService");
```

The string "NetTcpBinding_IFooService" is the `name` attribute of the `binding` element in app.config.

**Create channel**

```
fooService = fooServiceFactory.CreateChannel();
```

**Use it**

```
fooService.DoSomething();
```

The trickiest part is getting app.config right. You need to learn about *bindings* and *endpoints*. It's a bit of a learning curve, but nothing drastic.

Comment: The OP is indicating that he has discovered that creating the proxies manually is a best practice, and is looking recommended ways to do this.

Answer (score 9):

Here are the basic steps.

1. Create your service like normal.
2. Move the interface that your service implements into an assembly that can be shared with   the client.
3. Create a ChannelFactory where T is your interface.  You will have to give the uri of your service to the constructor.
4. Call factory.CreateChannel().  This will be type T.
5. Use the channel to make calls.

It is really that simple.  No auto generated code, no service references.  It gets a little more complicated with async calls and Silverlight, but not too much.