# How to return my complex types from a wcf service, not model itself?

Tags: c#, wcf, model-view-controller

I have a separate layer for my complex types as `DataAccessLayer`(DAL), as well as a separate layer for business as `BusinessLogicLayer`(BL).
I create a wcf service application project as `ServiceLayer`(SL) and i added my service that use BL methods and DAL complex type for return value.

Now,i have a one problem in add refrence from myService in my mvc project and it is that :

> When added my refrence of myService, in Refrence.cs generate itself complex type for each myComplex type that used it.

I want not generate itself complex type and use of my complex type at DAL.

**DAL**

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace DAL
{
    [DataContract]
    public partial class MyComplexType 
    {
        //... 
        [DataMember]
        //my prop
        //...
    }
}
```

**BL**

```
namespace BL
{
    public partial class MyRepository
    {
        public List<DAL.MyComplexType> MyMethod(int param1,int param2) 
        {
            var parameters= new List<SqlParameter>();
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Param1",SqlDbType.Int){ Value = param1 });
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Param2",SqlDbType.Int){ Value = param2 });
            var result = DAL.RunProcedure("MyProc", parameters);
            return result.ConvertToList<DAL.MyComplexType>();
        }
    }
}
```

**SL**

```
namespace SL
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<DAL.MyComplexType> MyServiceMethod(int param1,int param2);
    }
}

namespace SL
{
    public class MyService : IMyService
    {
        public List<DAL.MyComplexType> MyServiceMethod(int param1, int param2) 
        {
            BL.MyRepository bl = new BL.MyRepository();
            List<DAL.MyComplexType> result = bl.MyMethod(param1, param2);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

**Refrence.cs** class In **MyMvcProject** after added MyService refrence service :

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.34014
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace MyMvcProject.MyService
{
    using System.Data;

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName = "MyService.IMyService")]
    public interface IMyService
    {
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://tempuri.org/IMyService/MyServiceMethod", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/IMyService/MyServiceMethodResponse")]
        [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
        MyMvcProject.MyService.MyServiceMethodResponse MyServiceMethod(MyMvcProject.MyService.MyServiceMethodRequest request);

        // CODEGEN: Generating message contract since the operation has multiple return values.
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IMyService/MyServiceMethod", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IMyService/MyServiceMethodResponse")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<MyMvcProject.MyService.MyServiceMethodResponse> MyServiceMethodAsync(MyMvcProject.MyService.MyServiceMethodRequest request);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.33440")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DAL")]
    public partial class MyComplexType : object {

        //private props ...
        //..

        /// <remarks/>
        //public props
    }
    //.... other bloks
}
```

> Return type of used service refrence mthod is
>   **MyMvcProject.MyService.MyComplexType**

```
MyMvcProject.MyService.MyServiceClient service = new MyMvcProject.MyService.MyServiceClient();

MyMvcProject.MyService.MyComplexType result = service.MyServiceMethod(10,12);
```

Insted of :

```
DAL.MyComplexType result = service.MyServiceMethod(10,12);
```

How to resolved it?
What is the problem?

**Edited**

My vs version is 2013.

I test this method in `WPF` project and result ok,that means service not create self complex type and use from DAL complex type.

But in `MVC` project both with cheked and unchecked the `Reuse types in refrenced assemblies` in service configuration service create self complex types.

I do not know how to resolve this problem or what is the reason ?

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh,I want use from tow methods, both service and business, and want both use of one complex type of DAL and not use to convert types

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't works like that, specially when you are adding service reference. Remember that it doesn't reference an **actual DLL** in your client once you are adding service reference.

Upon serializing your datacontract it re-create its own classes that serializer can recognize and only matter by adding Namespaces and upon deserializing in service it only check the Namespace to identity what equivalent object/class in actual object in your service:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DAL")]
    public partial class MyComplexType : object {
       . . . 
    }
```

If you want to use your own DAL in client why don't just create client proxy or channelfactory programmatically and physically add your DAL.

Take a look at this links on how to create proxy programmatically:

- [Create WCF Client without auto generated proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361646/create-wcf-client-without-auto-generated-proxy)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Can you explain that more should I do?

Comment: There is no way to achieve this `DAL.MyComplexType result = service.MyServiceMethod(10,12);` if you are adding service reference. As you can see if you are adding service reference it create new MyComplexType.

Comment: ok, how to create client proxy or channelfactory programmatically and physically add your DAL?

Comment: There is no way to achieve this `DAL.MyComplexType result = service.MyServiceMethod(10,12);` if you are adding service reference. As you can see if you are adding service reference it create new MyComplexType.

If you want to use your DAL.MyComplexType in your client then adding service reference in not the path to take. See this link to create your proxy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361646/create-wcf-client-without-auto-generated-proxy and then add reference of your DAL in client.

Comment: tanks, i've tested both methods, but in both methods generate itself complex type!!!

Comment: **Note :** for other service same this service that use DAL.MyComplex type not generate itself complex type and correct work.