# Skipping App.config configuration and configuring in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, config

If I want to remove necessity of app.config configuration from my  **Client side** code and initialize client from my c#. Defining Bindings and EndPoint in my C# code. What would be a c# version of following client side code:

```
<client>
            <endpoint address="http://employeetstsvc/Employee.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="StandardEndpoint" contract="ServiceReference2.IHREmployee"
                name="StandardEndpoint" />
        </client>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Something like below. See more [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731080%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
String baseAddress = "http://employeetstsvc/Employee.svc";

WSHttpBinding binding1 = new WSHttpBinding();

using(ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Employee)))
{
   host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ServiceReference2.IHREmployee),binding1, baseAddress);
}
```

Comment: This is actually client side configuration. Seems like the answer you sugegste is server side. I am sorry I should had been more specific. I updated my question so that there is no more confusion

Comment: @CoffeeBean, didn't you say that *initialize client from my c# defining Bindings and EndPoint in my C# code*? Bit confused now...

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. I am just coding the client. `"http://employeetstsvc/Employee.svc"` already exists. and I want to call that service but I want to skip the app.config configuration and initialize the proxy from the C# code

Comment: @CoffeeBean, Uhh!!! You mean, don't want to create the proxy using service reference and directly from code?

Comment: @CoffeeBean, What you are looking for is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361646/create-wcf-client-without-auto-generated-proxy

Comment: Well to backtrack a little bit. When I added the service reference in my client side code, it created Proxy class in 'reference.cs'. However though, it  did not add any <ServiceModel> configurations in my app.config. So I am trying to invoke the client from my C# code and define <ServiceModel> in code rather than depending on config file.