# Autofac with wcf

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, autofac, single-instance

```
   builder.Register(c => new ChannelFactory<IBuildingInfoService>
    ("BasicHttpBinding_IBuildingInfoService"))
                .SingleInstance();


    builder.Register(c => c
    .Resolve<ChannelFactory<IBuildingInfoService>>().CreateChannel())
               .As<IBuildingInfoService>()
               .UseWcfSafeRelease();
```

I have got these lines of code in dependency injection for WCF client..

Can somebody explain how does it work.. ?

How does single instance work ?

What is channel Factory doing internally ?

Answer (score 2):

> [SingleInstance](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#single-instance)

The above is creating a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). You will get the same instance every time you request it.

[There are different ways to create a WCF Client and Channel Factory is one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698275/wcf-channelfactory-vs-generating-proxy). The Channel Factory class is used to construct a channel between the client and server without creating a proxy.

When you create a channel factory - it calls `Open` internally.

You can see the [source code here](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/WCF/WCF/3@5@30729@1/untmp/Orcas/SP/ndp/cdf/src/WCF/ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/ChannelFactory@cs/1/ChannelFactory@cs) and if you dig into it, `CreateChannel` eventually calls `EnsuredOpen`.

```
    protected void EnsureOpened()
    { 
        base.ThrowIfDisposed();
        if (this.State != CommunicationState.Opened)
        {
            lock (this.openLock) 
            {
                if (this.State != CommunicationState.Opened) 
                { 
                    this.Open();
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: But how can i Test it and check whether two instances returned are the one and the same.. because when i tested resolving two instances back to back and compared them with == operator i got false result.

Comment: @Abi That's a different question than the one you posted. That being said, you can try Object.ReferenceEquals https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals(v=vs.110).aspx