# C# and jirasoapservice

Tags: c#, .net, jira

In a Visual Studio .NET project, right click the project references and choose 'Add Service Reference', enter the URL of JIRA's WSDL descriptor (http://localhost:8080/rpc/soap/jiraservice-v1.wsdl)

Visual Studio coudn't auto-generate a .NET class for accessing the JIRA SOAP API.

"Custom tool warning: Fault named RemoteException in operation getComment cannot be imported. 
Unsupported WSDL, the fault message part must reference an element. This fault message does not reference an element. 
If you have edit access to the WSDL document, you can fix the problem by referencing a schema element using the 'element' attribute."

I doing somthing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using WCF.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3789812/941776) suggests you to use `svcutil.exe` from the command line to generate your class and then add this class to your project.