# Web Reference And Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, web-services, wcf

I am developing an application. I have a wcf service (which is not hosted by iis), well When I add this service in a winform project as "service reference"

[image]

so everything looks fine..

and if i add the same service to an asp.net project

[image]

As you can see, it seems different, and on the left list, there are some functions name which belong to IDMOBJ (on first photo you can see) and there is no IDMSvc. And when I add the service, I cant see some classes of service which are so important.

I dont know what is the reason. This service is given to me by company, means, I cant change any settings on the WCF service.

if you ask me why you add /?wsdl, if I dont, I got http 405 error like that

[image]

but If I add the service link to winform project without "/?wsdl", it works also, it just doesnt work on the web project.

So, We have been trying to solve this problem for 2 weeks but havent any result yet. What should I do for it?

Comment: Can't you just add a _service reference_, not a _web reference_?

Comment: I can add as a web reference also, but the problem, I cant see the some classes of the service. For example, in this service there are 100 classes, but I can just see 90 classes on object browser.. For example I need these classes DMSvcClient ve DMObjClient but, I cant see them on the web service.. thank you for reply

Comment: Are you in control of both the web services and the client?

Comment: I cant the control web service, thats why I cant change anything on the service. But yes I can control client..

Comment: Why are you adding it as a service reference in the winform project but as a web reference in the asp.net project?

Comment: in winform, just testing. I need to add i as web reference. But its problem.. And after i tried it on winform, it is OK. Problem is when I add the service on a web proj. as web ref., some classes are not shown.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158106/web-reference-vs-service-reference

Comment: @sr28, thank you for the link, its completely opposite of my situation. Because on the link, how to add a web reference on a non-web project. But my situation is, how i can add a service to a web project as web reference. When i try to add web reference on asp.net project, there is no option as "Advanced", there is just on non-web projects..

Comment: maybe the problem is just in the list of operations in that form, but when you actually add the reference it is created correctly. add the reference and see which methods are available on which interface.