# Add service reference gives Exception: Unable to connect to remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, web

My WCF service returns result when calling from console application client. However, it's showing

> Exception: Unable to connect to remote server

Actual Error:

> Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match
>   the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for
>   more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring
>   to default configuration, or refreshing the service.

Error details:

> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.
>   For more information about the error, either turn on
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute
>   or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in
>   order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on
>   tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and
>   inspect the server trace logs.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message
>   reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version,
>   FaultConverter faultConverter)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at IJiraService.GetProjects()    at
>   JiraServiceClient.GetProjects()

***Please note that, when Fiddler is running, the service is working fine.However, if I close Fiddler, then it shows exception:***

This is Fiddler log(while I'm getting the data):

TTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
Date: Thu, 06 Aug 2015 14:39:22 GMT
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Via: 1.1 localhost.localdomain

Encrypted HTTPS traffic flows through this CONNECT tunnel. HTTPS Decryption is enabled in Fiddler, so decrypted sessions running in this tunnel will be shown in the Web Sessions list.

Secure Protocol: Tls
Cipher: Aes128 128bits
Hash Algorithm: Sha1 160bits
Key Exchange: ECDHE_RSA (0xae06) 256bits

== Server Certificate ==========
[Subject]
  CN=*.atlassian.net, O="Atlassian Network Services, Inc.", L=San Francisco, S=California, C=US

[Issuer]
  CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US

[Serial Number]
  08E828A2F8C521A2DC7121A28E191837

[Not Before]
  9/9/2014 5:30:00 AM

[Not After]
  11/15/2017 5:30:00 PM

[Thumbprint]
  EA57BE3C6CDA33E6D875889944EE61284E39D91D

---

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 06 Aug 2015 14:39:26 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-AREQUESTID: 39x4118x1
X-ASEN: SEN-2425233
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=8B68E46928883CA9F99382A67C228541; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: studio.crowd.tokenkey=""; Domain=.clientname.atlassian.net; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
X-Seraph-LoginReason: OUT
Set-Cookie: studio.crowd.tokenkey=YcO0N1IItmmGYah6bzgN0w00; Domain=.clientname.atlassian.net; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
X-Seraph-LoginReason: OK
Set-Cookie: atlassian.xsrf.token=ALMX-0SVV-VVCK-3Y73|c420e5bfab5c997ccdfa21ffa129d60a69af0013|lin; Path=/; Secure
X-ASESSIONID: b2v6it
X-AUSERNAME: admin
X-ATENANT-ID: clientname.atlassian.net
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, no-transform
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=315360000;includeSubDomains

**As per above Fiddler log is Something I must change in web.config file to make it work?**

when called from WCF test client. Here is what I have tried:

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
  <!--<system.net>
   <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" >
  </defaultProxy>
 </system.net>-->
<appSettings>
<add key="UserName" value="admin"/>
<add key="Password" value="admin"/>
<add key="resturl" value="https://Clientname.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/"/>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
 <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
 </system.web>
 <system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IJiraService"/>
    </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
   <client>
     <endpoint address="http://localhost:19065/JiraService.svc"  binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IJiraService" contract="ServiceReference1.IJiraService"
       name="BasicHttpBinding_IJiraService" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
     <serviceBehaviors>
       <behavior>
         <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
         <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
       </behavior>
       </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
      <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
   </protocolMapping>    
   <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"   multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
   <!--
    To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
    Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
  -->
  <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
 </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Here is how I'm requesting in my code:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    private string GetRestURL()
    {
        return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["resturl"];
    }

    private string GetUserName()
    {
        return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyUserName"];
    }

    private string GetPassword()
    {
        return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyPassword"];
    }

 public string method()
 {
       HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        // HttpClient 


        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
        //request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=UTF-8";
        /*request.Headers.Add("X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck");
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        request.KeepAlive = true;*/
        request.Method = method;

        /*if (data != null)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(),Encoding.ASCII))
            {
                writer.Write(data);
            }
        }*/
        string base64Credentials = GetEncodedCredentials();
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);



     try
     {
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);

        response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse; //here its NULL

        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Server error (HTTP {0}:{1}).",response.StatusCode,response.StatusDescription));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) //Here I'm getting exception
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
 }
```

Here is my method signature:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<ProjectDescription> GetProjects();
 }
```

Note: the "method" is getting called from "GetProjects"

This is the inner exception I'm getting when debugging by invoking WCF test client:

This is I'm getting inner exception

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly     respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 165.254.xxx.xxx:443

NOTE: There is no debug exception when I'm debugging from console application. as I said, console application is working fine and I'm able to return the result from the service.

**UPDATE:** When I'm adding this service in console application as "Add reference", it's working fine. However, when I add as "Add service reference" in the same console application, it's showing me same error. Is it my web is blocking something? Please help.

How to correct this? Is there something else I need to add in `web.config`? OR do I need to allow the URL as trusted URL somewhere?

Comment: can you show us the signature of your `REST` service method?

Comment: Updated my question with signature.

Comment: If I understand correct - you set up http connection, I am not? But from error message I see that you are connecting to https (443) port. Could it be your problem?

Comment: instead of `"Basic " + base64Credentials` try `string.Format("{0}{1}","Basic " ,base64Credentials`).

Comment: Do I need to configure proxy somehow in my code or config file.Found something here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1180127.aspx?A+connection+attempt+failed+because+the+connected+party+did+not+properly+respond+after+a+period+of+time+or+established+connection+failed+because+connected+host+has+failed+to+respond+
But, not sure, how can i implement this in my case.

Comment: Whole config file is shown in question, anything I need to modify in config?

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved by adding proxy in IIS. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this answer?  It sounds like it resolves the kind of issue you're experiencing:

[Web Reference vs. Service Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158106/web-reference-vs-service-reference)

Answer (score 0):

Try to adjust your bindings for HTTPS and make sure to configure for http also.

```
<protocolMapping>
  <!--<add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>-->
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
  <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https"     bindingConfiguration="WebBinding"/>
</protocolMapping>
```