# WCF service is working when Fiddler is running .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, fiddler, wireshark

[image: My Browser proxy now]If I'm not running fiddler then my WCF throws exception : "Add service reference gives Exception": Unable to connect to remote server.

However, everything works fine while running fiddler. How to know what fiddler is doing and what change I should do accordingly in my WCF code to make it work without fiddler? Please suggest?

I'm trying to analyse this using WireShark.But, I'm new to this tool and finding difficulty.

Note: I found, there is a another server sitting between my client and the server from where I'm trying to get data.

Comment: show us some code and the exact point the exception is raising

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31579822/add-service-reference-gives-exception-unable-to-connect-to-remote-server

Answer (score 0):

if you run fiddler, it will change your proxy settings in the browser. That also can cause this issue.

check the proxy settings in IE.

Comment: Will changing browser proxy will work ?Could you please tell me steps to  I correct my browser proxy? I wanted to run this code without fiddler.

Comment: This is not an answer.Make comments in comments section next to question.