# Visual Studio 2015 Add Service Reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Apparently, it was possible in Visual Studio to right click on project in the Solution Manager and "Add Service Reference". This seems not possible in Visual Studio 2015. I am building a Console App. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I see `Add Service Reference` when i right click on `References` of a project in vs2015.  Also I believe it's always in the `Project` menu.

Comment: There is this option in vs2015. What is your target framework? Maybe this helps https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f295973f-5679-468d-8353-8ae26fa5889f/cannot-add-service-reference?forum=wcf

Comment: @Jonesopolis Maybe you dont have a console app

Comment: @west123 I am using a console app. what .NET version are you using?

Comment: You Sent the same link as the Person above. None of them work

Comment: For what it's worth, I have the same problem. I changed it to a WinForms app and the option to add a service reference appeared.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a web service reference in Visual Studio 2015 to a console app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852448/how-to-add-a-web-service-reference-in-visual-studio-2015-to-a-console-app)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in VS2015; perhaps you are still running your application. Make sure your application has been stopped.

Comment: Can you also share how to do it? Just pointing out that it is possible is usually not enough.

Comment: Go to your Solution Manager, find the project you want to add the reference to, right click on references and click Add Service Reference, again remember to stop your application before doing this, otherwise it will be grayed out.