# ASP.NET web forms - how to asynchronously call WCF asynchronous method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, asynchronous

I have created a WCF service and hosted it in IIS.  I can access the WCF service by creating a web reference in my asp.net web forms application.  I need to have the WCF web service run a long running method (async).  Does anyone have good example code of how to call a WCF asynchronous method from an asp.net web forms application button click method?

I have looked at IAsyncResult, EAP, and TAP...
What currently is the best way to make an asynchronous call to a WCF asynchronous method from a ASP.NET web forms application?

I did now change my code to use a Service Reference instead of a Web reference.

Service ReceiptFooterService (ServiceContract, OperationsContract, DataContract):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ReceiptFooterDeploymentService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IReceiptFooterService
    {
        [OperationContract(Name = "GetRegisterPingResults")]
        Task<List<PingReply>> GetRegisterPingResults(List<StoreIP> potentialIPs);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class StoreIP
    {
        private int _storeNumber;
        private string _ipAddress;

        [DataMember]
        public int StoreNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return _storeNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                _storeNumber = value;
            }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string IPAddress
        {
            get
            {
                return _ipAddress;
            }
            set
            {
                _ipAddress = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ReceiptFooterService class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ReceiptFooterDeploymentService
{
    public class ReceiptFooterService : IReceiptFooterService
    {
        public async Task<List<PingReply>> GetRegisterPingResults(List<StoreIP> potentialIPs)
        {
            var tasks = potentialIPs.Select(sip => new Ping().SendPingAsync(sip.IPAddress, 1000));
            var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

            return results.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

ASP.NET web forms client: Only first few lines of the method (for brevity)

```
private List<StoreDetail> PingStoreAndUpdateStatus(List<StoreDetail> storeDetails)
{
    ReceiptFooterService.StoreIP[] potentialIPs = GetStoreRegisterIps(storeDetails).ToArray();
    ReceiptFooterService.ReceiptFooterServiceClient client = new ReceiptFooterService.ReceiptFooterServiceClient();
    List<PingReply> pingReplies = client.GetRegisterPingResultsAsync(potentialIPs).Result.ToList();
```

I am attempting to ping approximately 2000 IP addresses asynchronously.  I am getting back four results that show success.  Although, none of the other PingReply details are showing.  I need to know what IP address was pinged.

Should I be awaiting somewhere... is that why it is returning to soon, or is there an error causing it to fail.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Below, is a QuickWatch of my results:

Comment: `I need to have the WCF web service run a long running method (async).` - [`async` does *not* yield control to the browser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx), if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: How do I get the browser to call back the service once it completes running the asynchronous pings?

Comment: I recommend using SignalR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using a WCF web service for the kind of asynchronous work I needed to do (was not working from in the web service).

I switched to creating a console application that I call with arguments, and then store the results in a database.  I then have the web site access the results stored in the database.

The console application context is much more friendly to completing the amount of asynchronous methods that I wanted to run at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

First, when using WCF why don't you use service reference?
([Web vs Service reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158106/web-reference-vs-service-reference))
Then, when using SOAP client, it automatically generates SOAP WCF client with each method with synchronous and `asynchronous` variant.

Then you just call this async method

> MyServiceClient.DummyMethodAsync(someParameters...)

Comment: It may help if I show my source code.  I will post that later.