# .net core add Web Reference

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-1.1, web-reference

I have two Web Project.

First of them is created about 2-3 weeks ago.
Second of them is created today.

I want to add Web Reference to the second web project.

First old Project Solution View

[image: First old Project Solution View]

Second new Project Solution View

[image]

In new Project I can't find how to add Web Reference.
I can add Service Reference but I don't need it.

From here I can add Service Reference

[image]

but I can't add Web Reference Like it was in old project

[image]

From where I should add Web Reference? Is there any changes regarding web references?

Comment: please check this link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WCFCORETEAM.VisualStudioWCFConnectedService

Comment: I already installed it, So i can add Service Reference.

Comment: Yes, you can add classic web service to your .core project.

Comment: I am getting this error 
_The service at the following URI does not have any endpoints compatible with .Net Core apps:'C:\Users\Luka\Desktop\Service.wsdl'_

I was getting this also, in old project, while adding as Service Reference.
but i added as Web Reference without this problem.

Comment: @LukinoGrdzelishvili .Net core WCF client support BasiHttpBinding only.

Comment: I used my old project in my new solution, and it works fine.

Comment: What is the project type you can't add reference to `WCF`? If it is an `ASP.NET Core` application you can do that via intermediary `Standard` class library. See the details here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50624568/804385

Comment: It is core 2.0.
I have made it using old Web Api project and .net core app uses it like rest api.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web Reference vs. Service Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158106/web-reference-vs-service-reference)

Comment: @DmitryPavlov I asked this question for .Net Core. if you see your linked question is 9 years old and .net core isn't as old as that question. so that question can't be useful for .net core.

Comment: @LukinoGrdzelishvili `Web Reference` (as it was in the past) doesn't exist anymore for `.NET Core` projects. Did you try using `Add Connected Serrvice` -> `Microsfot WCF Web Service Reference Provider` and provide your `WSDL` link to re-generate proxy class for your web reference?

Comment: @DmitryPavlov Yes, I tried it. but that service is old, and i think they used different endpoint configuration from .net core support. 
I am gettubg error: "The service at the following URI does not have any endpoints compatible with .Net Core apps:'C:\Users\Luka\Desktop\Service.wsdl' ".

I made .net framework web api project and included this wsdl using it.

Comment: @LukinoGrdzelishvili would you try `Web Services Description Language Tool (Wsdl.exe)` to generate C# code using command line?

Comment: @LukinoGrdzelishvili what service are you trying to call? `Add Service Reference`  (WCF) should be used in almost all cases, when the remote service complies with SOAP 1.1 at least and uses *standardized* extensions like those introduced in the WS-* Interoperability standards around 2003-2007. The generated WCF proxy understands and *implements eg WS-Authentication.  `Add Web Service Reference` is older and laxer.

Comment: @LukinoGrdzelishvili Unfortunately, many big companies like banks and airlines created their services before 2007 using extensions that never became part of the standard, like ebXML or SOAP Attachments. And since the are Big, they never bothered fixing their services (looking at Sabre). You can *still* use the old code, as the classes are the same. Whether you can use `Add Service Reference` or `svcutil` to add a *new* reference depends on how non-compliant the service is. If you tell the tool to use XmlSerializer it can generate classes most of the time

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for answer. It's very old and that time I made another adapter service which was on .net framework.
P.S. you are right, they had some custom stuff there and that's why .net core 2.1 couldn't reference it.

Answer (score 0):

- Select old project in Solution Explorer.
- Click 'Show All Files' button `Solution Explorer` toolbar.
- `Service` node will be expanded and you will see the nested nodes with generated code.
- You should find the link to `WSDL` file, which describes your web service.
- To load a service metadata from a `WSDL` file, select [`Browse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide) in `Add Web Reference` dialog.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide) states:

> The WCF Web Service Reference tool retrieves metadata from a web
> service in the current solution, on a network location, or from a WSDL
> file, and generates a source file containing Windows Communication
> Foundation (WCF) client proxy code that your .NET app can use to
> access the web service.

Comment: This does not add it in a compatible way.

Comment: What do you mean @MotKohn ?

Comment: the generated reference.cs even when doing it your prescribed way with loading the file from old project is not usable and does not match at all what the add reference looked like when using .net>Add References>Advanced>Add Web Reference. See https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/3750

Comment: @MotKohn that's simply wrong and the link you point to has nothing to do with *non* WCF services. Anyone who had to migrate code using non-WS-* compliant services like those used by airlines and banks from .NET Framework to .NET Core actually copied the old source. WCF is pretty strict about SOAP compliance and many of the *big* companies (like Sabre) created their services using Oracle's proposals that never became standard. ASMX/Add Web References is more lenient

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I would try in a command line:

- cd "Full path to folder where ConsoleApp1 project lives"
- dotnet add package "Full path to Test projects .csproj file"

This command should edit your ConsoleApp1.csproj file. 
Then you can try to build it with:

- dotnet build