# Failure adding WCF service after cancelling

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I was trying to add a WCF service, I forgot to change the class name before clicking finish and so I cancelled it while it was in the first few steps of the import process.  I tried again with the proper name, and now I get the following error.

```
[8/24/2017 11:53:41.664 AM] Adding Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider - Preview to the project.
[8/24/2017 11:53:41.674 AM] Importing web service metadata ...
[8/24/2017 11:53:41.750 AM] Number of services found: 2
[8/24/2017 11:53:41.768 AM] Restoring NuGet packages ...
[8/24/2017 11:53:43.905 AM] Error:Unable to restore NuGet packages, please ensure packages can be restored for the project.
[8/24/2017 11:53:44.013 AM] Failed adding Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider - Preview to the project.
```

I tried re-installing WCF provider, rebooting, nothing seems to help.  Where can I look for a more detailed log as to why this is happening?  VS Pro 2017 15.3.1, .net core 2.0 web project

Answer (score 3):

**Workaround**

As adding [Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide) does not work for `ASP.NET Core 2.1` project [at the moment](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/5703), you can add new `.NET Standard` class library project targeted to `Standard 2.0` and add service reference to it:

- Right click on project
- Select `Add` -> `Connected Service`
- In `Connected Services` window select `Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider`
- Specify `WSDL` details as described the the [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide)
- Add new library reference to your `ASP.NET Core` web application
  (targeted to `.NET Core 2.1`)

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who's interested, https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2228
Seems upgrading from net core 1.1 to 2.0 kills the dotnet restore process because you have to remove PackageTargetFallback from the csproj