# Visual Studio 19. Don't add webasm service

Tags: c#, web, service, wsdl, asmx

I am trying to connect a web service(see http://www.cbr.ru/DailyInfoWebServ/DailyInfo.asmx?wsdl ) using the VS 2019 menu "Add Service Reference" as an asmx web service. The service is determined, a list of methods appears, but after adding the "Web service reference", a message appears after a while "Unable to download file from http://...?wsdl" Continue or Cancel. After continue created .disco file , and reference file , but it is empty! How to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you download the wsdl using other means? Browser, Curl, ... anything?

Comment: Yes, it’s downloaded without problem. I downloaded the file as an xml file, saved it to disk, and tried to create a link from it. As a result, a file was created with many classes (... handler and ...args) and without the methods themselves, it cannot be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options, "Add Web Reference" and "Add Service Reference". The former is for old-fashion asmx (like cbr service is) and [the latter is for WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158106/web-reference-vs-service-reference). Use "Add Web Reference" to add reference to that service and this will work. There are multiple tutorials and examples on the internet which shows how to use cbr:

- https://www.cbr.ru/development/DWS/
- https://books.google.de/books?id=_9Ebx5iI5EEC&pg=PA424
- etc.

Comment: Tank you! I use direct post SOAP package.

Comment: Glad it helped. Marked as anwered.