# Unable to create web reference for WSDL file

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-core, wsdl

I've created an ASP.Net core 3.1 project with Visual Studio 2019. I want to add a WSDL service as a `web reference`. But I can't. Why the `Advanced` button removed in this form.

Visual Studio 2019:

[image]

Old version:

[image]

I've read somewhere that, Web reference is deprecated.
How can I do it?

**UPDATE1:** The errors of documentation example code when I added it as a service reference

[image]

Comment: For what do you need the `advanced` features?

Comment: In the documentation of the service mentioned, I should add it as a `web reference`. When I add it as a `service reference`, the documentation sample code doesn't work.

Comment: Is your wsdl public? If so I can have a try

Comment: https://sms.magfa.com/api/soap/sms/v2/server?wsdl

Comment: If you just enter the URL, it seems to work

Comment: What is exactly you mean?

Comment: Adding it as `service reference` seems to work - what is exactly the problem you encounter?

Comment: The documentation has many examples. When I add the service as a `service reference` those examples don't work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158106/web-reference-vs-service-reference

Comment: Don't work can be due to a lot of things. We need details like error information, stacktraces etc.

Comment: There is no error. Is adds to the project successfully. But it seems the `service reference` and `web reference` are different(different interfaces).

Comment: You are saying it does not work? What is it that doesn't work?

Comment: I said, "The documentation has many examples. When I add the service as a service reference those examples don't work." But it successfully adds. There is no error to add.

Comment: My main question is not why my codes don't work. My question is how can I add the WSDL as a `web reference`.

Comment: There is no difference between them: it creates a client library - that's all that matters.

Answer (score 0):

You just should use the new method. The old one is deprecated - see the question in your comment: [Web Reference vs. Service Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158106/web-reference-vs-service-reference).

The last answers sums it like it is. In the end, the reference is just the creation of a client library to call the service. That's it.

> Adding a service reference allows you to create a WCF client, which can be used to talk to a regular web service provided you use the appropriate binding. Adding a web reference will allow you to create only a web service (i.e., SOAP) reference.
>
> If you are absolutely certain you are not ready for WCF (really don't know why) then you should create a regular web service reference.

(see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158137/2416958)

---

So, to "fix" your issue:

You need to include the `namespace` which you used to create the client on top of your file:

In my example:

```
using ServiceReference1;
```

But it can be different in your case. You can find it at the generated files, its called `ServiceReference1` in my case:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace ServiceReference1
{
    
    
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.1")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="webservice.magfa.com", ConfigurationName="ServiceReference1.MagfaSoapServer")]
    public interface MagfaSoapServer
    {
```

You need to create a new one with this:

```
var client = new MagfaSoapServerClient();
client.ClientCredentials = ...
```