# Adding a service reference to a website

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am trying to add a service reference to my website. When I add the service reference to a WPF application I get a reference.cs file that I can edit and add attributes to. When I try to do the same thing in a asp.net website there this file isn't present. I have also tried looking on the file system and the reference.cs isn't present. Can anyone provide some guidance?

EDIT:: Im using VS2010 and I need to edit the reference.cs to add [Webget] and [WebPost] attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manually edit a service stub, consider using [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx).

Comment: That seems to be the right aproach. Ill let you know how i get on

Comment: Hi, I am using .Net Core 2.0. While adding service my class name is `ABCService` but in .Net core it is generating `ABCServiceClient` event the properties and Method signature also changed. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, right-click on the reference under the "Service Reference" section of the Solution Explorer and click "View in Object Browser".  Then, in the Object Browser, under the namespace for the reference, right-click on any of the properties and select "Go to Definition".  This will load up "Reference.cs" file.

Hope this helps!

**Edit:**
Also worth noting is that the classes generated for you are partial classes, so it may be beneficial to consider extending them in a separate file so that you can still "Update" the reference and not have the generated code overwrite any changes you make.  This would all depend on what you're planing on modifying though.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of VS it will create a folder under the project root. In my case under VS2010 I added a ref to http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL, set the namespace to `ServiceReference1` and it created a folder in the project root called `\Service References\ServiceReference1` under which it stored all the ref files including Reference.cs

If you are not seeing this folder then there may be something wrong at your service that VS is unable to query the WSDL and generate the files. Try the stock service above to test.

And editing the generated files is usually a bad idea as they can get regenerated when you refresh the reference. Unless you want to rip the generated code out and never refresh it again.

**UPDATE:**

---

- Seems like that webservicex service is slow, try [this](http://www.ripedevelopment.com/webservices/LocalTime.asmx?WSDL)
- Also, seems like there is a diff between "Web Reference" and "Service Reference". See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308454/difference-between-web-reference-and-service-reference). But ultimately it creates a sub folder in your project root called either "Service References" or "Web References" with the sub folder of whatever you named your reference.