# Not able to call WCF service from local machine

Tags: wcf

I have created a WCF webservice using WCF Service Application template in VS 2008.
In the same solution i have created a web application project and added the web reference to the service where i gave the service url.

Now when i call the service method from my web application project, i get a timeout, i cannot get the O/P from calling service method. Here's my code i am using to call method from service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using WebApplicationClient.WCFService;

namespace WebApplicationClient
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Service1 svc1 = new Service1();
            String ex = svc1.GetData(1,true);


        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I have figured out the problem. I added a Web Reference to the service rather than the Service reference and it worked.Can anyone tell me the difference b/w the two?

Also when i run the WCF service , i get this message:
Run this command from Command window:

```
 svcutil.exe http://localhost:1787/Service1.svc?wsdl
```

But svcutil.exe is not recognised by the OS. I guess it is placed somehwere and i have to give the path also, is this the problem?Where can i find this?

Comment: Are your WCF services started up?

Comment: @RQDQ Yes, i have figured out the problem. I added a Web Reference to the service rather than the Service reference and it worked.Can you tell me the difference b/w the two?

Comment: Web reference is the older web service stack (SOAP only I believe).  Service reference is the newer WCF stack.   However, if you were able to set a web reference, it should have worked fine...

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308454/difference-between-web-reference-and-service-reference) for some explanation.

Comment: @RQDQ No it is not working with WEb Reference.Also i have edited the questions with a few more doubts.

Comment: @CodeCaster , So does this mean if i add a Service reference i can only communicate within .NET(i.e. the client should also be build using WCF) and i use Add web reference if clients from other platforms would also communicate with my Service.

Comment: From the link that @CodeCaster gave, there's a statement which says "It is perfectly possible (though not recommended) to add a Web Reference that points to a WCF service, as long as the WCF endpoint uses basicHttpBinding or some compatible custom variant." Now i added the WCF service which by default is using the wsHttpBinding, so i guess i cannot use Add web reference, but why? And if i change it to basicHttpBinding, i just have to modify the web.config, no more changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But svcutil.exe is not recognised by the OS. I guess it is placed
>   somehwere and i have to give the path also, is this the problem?Where
>   can i find this?

`SvcUtil.exe` is the utility that helps to create proxy for a wcf service. You can easily access the utility by opening the Visual Studio command prompt not the windows command prompt.

If you have installed VS in C drive it would be located here.

```
C:\Program Files\ Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC
```

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308454/difference-between-web-reference-and-service-reference) talks about the difference between Add Web Reference and Add Service Reference. In your case I would suggest to use Service Reference not Web Reference.

Comment: I get an error when i try to run it.Error: Cannot create output file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\V
C\Service1.cs

    Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\Service1
.cs' is denied.  I donot have admin rights , is this the problem? Can i change the path where it generates the o/p.

Comment: Once you opened the VS command prompt just move to some other drive say D: or E: and then invoke the svcutil.exe. Ex. D:\>svcutil.exe http://localhost:1787/Service1.svc?wsdl

Comment: I cannot do CD D:, dont know why, i will try the same at my home machine and see if it works.