# Web Reference used on Visual Studio 2012 instead of Service Reference

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

Hi i have created WCF on my VS 2012 and i added it on my new Web Application. (.NET 4.5)

The Problem is that i cannot see my WCF Service namespace.

Then i tried to use Add Web Reference under compatibility, then it works.

What is the essence of Service Reference on Visual Studio 2012 where you still be using Web Reference instead?

I know that Web Reference used on .net 2.0 and Service Reference is for .net 3.0 and higher.

Does anyone can provide the details to deal with this Issue. Or do i missing something.

Comment: Here's a link to a discussion that might interest you. Basically the difference between web and service referencing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308454/difference-between-web-reference-and-service-reference

Comment: `Web Reference` = old-style, "legacy" ASMX webservices - not recommended for new development; `Service Reference` = WCF (Windows Communication Foundation) - this is the way to go for now and the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already find the solution.

The problem is Newtonsoft.Json dll on visual studio 2012.

What i did is remove first Newtonsoft.Json dll on reference before adding service reference on my project then add Newtonsoft.Json dll again.

After that you can add service reference that you want on your project.