# Calling methods on an old Web Service build in .Net 2.0 from a WCF Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, wcf

This is an bit of an unknown for me but ill go ahead and ask anyway.

Our company has an old legacy webservice which is no longer maintained built on .NET 2. Adding a "Web Reference" to a client project in visual studio allows us to query this web service without any issues.

A 3rd party has asked if it is possible to query this web service via their website via WCF by adding a "Service Reference" in visual studio. They have tried and failed.

This is not really my area, so id like an indication if this is actually possible?

Thanks

EDIT: The 3rd party get a 200 OK response back from any requests they make.

Comment: What's kind of error ?

Comment: They are getting a 200 OK response back from any requests.

Answer (score 0):

To do this they have to click add service reference then click advanced then click the button on the bottom under compatibility labeled add web reference.

It won't work if you just try to add a regular service reference.

[image]

Comment: We already know that it works with a Web Reference. I'm trying to determine if it can work with a Service Reference. Do you know for sure it cannot work with service reference. If so why?

Comment: For a more detail read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308454/difference-between-web-reference-and-service-reference