# Adding a service reference in VS 2017 15.9.14 windows forms application

Tags: wcf, service-reference, connected-services

I am trying to add a asmx web service to one windows forms app by following way ->
Right click- > add service reference.
But it seems the service is added under connected service folders only. not under service reference . Is this an expected behavior?
or are we supposed to use web reference instead of service reference for windows forms application?

Comment: It is a normal behavior, XML web service is also an implement of SOAP web service. In order to call this kind of web service, a client proxy class is generated in the reference.cs
We can invoke the service as if it were a local method.
ServiceReference1.WebService1SoapClient client = new WebService1SoapClient();
            var result = client.HelloWorld();
            Console.WriteLine(result);

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question you need to know the difference between Webservice and **WCF web service** and you'll find that
[Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308454/difference-between-web-reference-and-service-reference)

Anyway, I'ts a noraml behavior, let's form that in another words, the Service reference will let you communicate with a WCF-based services whatever those services are, but with the web reference, you can only communicate with web services under some conditions.
I would use service reference always because it gives more options including those in web service, and it's the new-easy way.